# Button wtih absolute position inside KeyboardAvoidingView "overwriting" other elements

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, styled-components

I have a button with absolute position, used for a form. When inside a KeyboardAvoidingView it goes on top of the other elements

```
const BtnContainer = styled.View`
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 38px;
  left: 16px;
  width: ${Dimensions.get('window').width - 32};
`

    <KeyboardAvoidingView
      behavior="padding"
      enabled
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      keyboardVerticalOffset={60}
    >
        // form content
        <BtnContainer>
          <Button
            text={getButtonLabel()}
            disabled={!isButtonEnabled()}
            onPress={stepChangeCallBack}
          />
        </BtnContainer>
    </KeyboardAvoidingView>
```

[image]

I tried `behavior="position"` and it breaks all the layout and `behavior="height"` also doesn't work.

Comment: Are you referring to the pink layout which is overlaying on top of the input field?

Comment: Yes, that’s the button

Comment: There seems to be a bug related to absolutely positioned elements inside a `KeyboardAvoidingView`: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/28697